# how can i do unit test of this method?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

How can i do unit test of this method

```
public static ICollection<Person> SelectPersonByCountry(string Country, LinkedList<Person> personList)  
    {  
        ICollection<Person> selectedPerson = new List<Person>();  
          if (Country != String.Empty)   
        {  
            foreach (Person item in personList)  
            {  
                  if (item.Country.ToUpper().Equals(Country.ToUpper()))
                  {  
                    selectedPerson.Add(item);  
                }  
            }  
        }  
        else  
        {  
            // do something  
            return null;  
        }  
        return selectedPerson;
```

Method CollectionAssert.AreEqual() wants 2 arguments ICollection and ICollection but i have
generic ICollections. What do i need to do?

```
public void TestMethod1()
    {
        string country = "Ukraine";

        LinkedList<lab1.Person> personList = new LinkedList<lab1.Person>();
        personList.AddFirst(new Person("Dasda", "Sasha", "Ukraine", "23131", "Ukrainian"));
        personList.AddFirst(new Person("Sasa", "OLeg", "Ukraine", "23131", "Ukrainian"));
        personList.AddFirst(new Person("Popa", "Sveta", "Ukraine", "23131", "Ukrainian"));
        personList.AddFirst(new Person("Bezik", "Vitya", "Ukraine", "23131", "Ukrainian"));
        personList.AddFirst(new Person("Hoi", "Oleg", "Ukraine", "23131", "Ukrainian"));
        ICollection<Person> expected = new LinkedList<Person>();
        expected.Add(new Person("Dasda", "Sasha", "Ukraine", "23131", "Ukrainian"));
        expected.Add(new Person("Sasa", "OLeg", "Ukraine", "23131", "Ukrainian"));
        expected.Add(new Person("Popa", "Sveta", "Ukraine", "23131", "Ukrainian"));
        expected.Add(new Person("Bezik", "Vitya", "Ukraine", "23131", "Ukrainian"));
        expected.Add(new Person("Hoi", "Oleg", "Ukraine", "23131", "Ukrainian"));


        ICollection expected1 = (ICollection)expected;

        ICollection actual = (ICollection)lab1.Person.SelectPersonByCountry(country, personList);



        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected1, actual );



    }
```

My method have to return collection like expected becouse of all my Person from "Ukraine", but test didn't pass..

Comment: It wants expected collection and the actual one. I don't think it matters that you are using generic collection.

Answer (score 3):

> Method CollectionAssert.AreEqual() wants 2 arguments ICollection and ICollection but i have generic ICollections. What do i need to do?

Most generic collections also implement the non-generic `ICollection` interface, so you can pass a generic collection anyway.

```
ICollection actual = (ICollection)SelectPersonByCountry(country, personList);
ICollection expected = new[] { person1, person2 };

CollectionAssert.AreEqual(actual, expected);
```

Comment: Oh,thanks you, but my test didn't pass but i have the same collections

Comment: Are you sure that your collection have the same order of elements?

Comment: @user2865903, did you override Equals in the Person class? If you didn't, two identical but distinct instances of Person will be considered different.

Answer (score 2):

There are actually two (potential) reasons for this:

First, the order of your lists. To add elements to personList you use addFirst, which prepends the element to the list. To add elements to expected you use Add, which appends the element to the list. Yet, you pass the persons in the same order. Therefore, expected and personList have reversed order. The Doc of CollectionsAssert.AreEquals states that

> the collections must have the same count, and contain the exact same objects in the same order.

Second, Person may not redefine Equals. If this is the case, C# defaults to reference equality, what means that

```
new Person("Dasda", "Sasha", "Ukraine", "23131", "Ukrainian")
  .Equals(new Person("Dasda", "Sasha", "Ukraine", "23131", "Ukrainian")) == false
```

There are three ways to resolve this issue:

1. Override Equals (and HashCode) in your Person class
2. Create the Person instances once and use them in both the expected and the personList lists. This solution would also reduce the risk of typos, btw. But it makes your test depend on the implementation , which needs to return the same instances.
3. Use CollectionAssert.AreEqual(IEnumerable, IEnumerable, IComparer) to define the equality relation outside of the Person class. Remember that you should write test for the IComparer then!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, while I've never used CollectionAssert.AreEqual, I'm pretty sure this is going to be related to how the underlying object comparison of each element in the collection is performed. The [AreEqual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243763.aspx) doco states;

> Elements are equal if their values are equal, not if they refer to the
>   same object. The values of elements are compared using [Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k.aspx) by
>   default.

My guess is that you need to make sure that your Person object implements the Equals method to allow object comparison. The link to the equals method above states;

> The static Equals(Object, Object) method indicates whether two
>   objects, objA and objB, are equal. It also enables you to test objects
>   whose value is null for equality. It compares objA and objB for
>   equality as follows:
>
> It determines whether the two objects represent
>   the same object reference.
>
> If they do, the method returns true. This
>   test is equivalent to calling the ReferenceEquals method. In addition,
>   if both objA and objB are null, the method returns true. It determines
>   whether either objA or objB is null. If so, it returns false. If the
>   two objects do not represent the same object reference and neither is
>   null, it calls objA.Equals(objB) and returns the result. This means
>   that if objA overrides the Object.Equals(Object) method, this override
>   is called.

See the examples at the [Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k.aspx) documentaion page for an idea on how to go about implementing this to ensure that one person object is actually the same as what you are expecting.

**Edit :** If you don't want to override Equals in your Person Object, then maybe create them once under where you define the country variable, and then add the same Person records to your LinkedList and your ICollection. That way, the reference is likely to be the same...I think.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I'm override my Equals method in Person and it works now.
I'm override like this, maybe it's badway but you can improve

```
  public override bool Equals(object objA)
  {
    Person person = objA as Person;
    if (person == null) return false;
    return (person.FirstName == this.FirstName && person.LastName == this.LastName && person.Language == this.Language && person.PersonId == this.PersonId)
  }
```